# How to redirect Upper path in nodejs/express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

im making posts, comment etc  i want to redirect upper route.
 im making delete post's comment.
 after delete, i want to redirect upper route, without a specific route

```
router.route('/post/comment/destroy/:postroot').post(function (req, res) {
    var database = req.app.get('database')
    var postroot = path.parse(req.params.postroot).base;
    var filterd = req.body.commentid;
    database.PostModel.findOne({
        "_id": postroot
    }, function (err, rawContent) {
        if (err) throw err;
        var idx;
        for (var i = 0; i < rawContent.comments.length ; i++){
            if (rawContent.comments[i]._id == filterd) {
                idx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        rawContent.comment.commentcount-=1;
        rawContent.comments.splice(idx, 1);

        rawContent.save(function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    });
    res.redirect(`/post/${postroot}`);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "upper route"?

Comment: i mean in case after delete comment at post1 redirect post1

Comment: And what does not work about your current code?

Comment: for example access post 1 by route /post1 , after delete comment in post1 at some route, i want to redirect /posts1 without specific route

Comment: thar code is work well but what i want to do is .. without specific route delclaration.. dleclaration every case is complicate.. so.. i want handle with some grammer evrey case

Comment: So why don't you do a `res.redirect('/post' + post.id);` or similar?

Comment: i rendering many posts at one ejs file simply change data ummm .....

Comment: I am really sorry, I still do not understand what exactly your question is.

Answer (score 0):

simply use your params inside the router

```
    res.redirect('/post/'+req.params.postroot);
```